# Populate last element of an array in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with an array field (`"array"`) that stores _ids which reference another collection. I am using mongoose's `.populate` and can populate a specific array element using the string dot notation, e.g.

`.populate({path: "array.4"})`

but I would now like to populate the last element of the array. In an ideal world, `"array.-1"` would work but it does not. I have tried using populate's `match` property with something like:

```
.populate({
  path: "array",
  match: { 
    $arrayElemAt: { 
      $subtract: [
        { 
          $size: "array"
        },
        1
      ]
    }
  },
})
```

but this doesn't work either (and I don't think is how it's supposed to be used at all!)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
User.find({},{"arrayObject": {$slice: -1})
  .populate('arrayObject')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is precisely what you're looking for but there is an easy way to do that for a *specific* document, which could help you do that for multiple. Let's imagine that your document's name is `User` and the array field that stores those ObjectIds is `hobbies`. So a sample doc may look like this:

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "hobbies": [
      ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
      ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002")
    ],
    "name": "James"
  }
```

You could populate the last element of the `hobbies` array for a *specific* user doing this:

```
    User.findById('5a934e000102030405000000')
        .then(user => {
            user.populate(`hobbies.${user.hobbies.length - 1}`, (err, u) => {
                console.log(u);
            });
        })
```

If you have multiple docs you want populated, I would do it like this fully realizing that depending on how many docs you have, this make be time consuming:

```
    User.find()
        .then(users => {
            const promises = users.map(user =>
                user.populate(`hobbies.${user.hobbies.length - 1}`).execPopulate()
            )
            Promise.all(promises).then(pop => {
                console.log(pop); //All populated with only last element of hobbies array
            })
        })
```